# DockerHubにあるDockerイメージのDockerfileを確認したい

Tags: docker

## 背景

DockerHubの`python:latest`イメージを使おうとしています。
https://hub.docker.com/_/python

このイメージについて、
* OSは何か？
* pythonコマンド以外にどんなコマンドを使えるか
などを知りたいです。

そのため、このイメージがどんなDockerfileでビルドされているかを確認したいです。
どこで確認すればよいでしょうか？

`tags`のページから遷移した以下のページには、Dockerfileのような情報が記載されていました.
`RUN`コマンドは記載されていませんでしたが、これはDockerfileに相当する情報でしょうか？
https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/latest/images/sha256-23d760aa4a5f2d46b12f439d113a8ffe5bf520c555b9c3aedb4765f9c8943024

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Description タブを開くと "Supported tags and respective Dockerfile links" にタグの一覧があり、
それぞれが Dockerfile にリンクされています。

latest については 現時点では [Debian 10 (buster)](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/c3233a936f58bee7c6899d3e381f23ed12cfc7a8/3.7/buster/Dockerfile) となるようです。

Comment: +1: そして、IMAGE HISTORY に書かれているのはおそらく [`docker history`](http://docs.docker.jp/engine/reference/commandline/history.html) 相当の情報です。